# How to make mmenu work with Omega 4 sub theme?

Tags: theming

I've used Omega 4 to create a mobile sub theme for my website and now would like to add a sliding menu. [Mobile sliding Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/mmenu) looks like exactly what I need but I can't make it work with Omega 4. When I follow the same steps with Bartik it works like a charm.
Can somebody share experience in using mmenu with Omega 4 or can at least point me in the right direction?

Any form of help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I haven't used that module but do use Omega and this module works well for the same sort of job https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_menus

Comment: I second the recommendation to use https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_menus, and specifically the Sidr style, which slides in from the left or right like Mobile Sliding Menu does. I have used Responsive Menus+ Sidr in a few Omega 4 sites and it works well.

Comment: Thanks guys. It does work and has quite few options. Wish I had found this before.